# When does Java Collections throw a NullPointerException while using Collections.addAll()

Tags: java, collections

Under what condition does the `Collections.addAll()` method throw a `NullPointerException`? The official docs mention:

> NullPointerException - if the specified collection contains a null element and this collection does not permit null elements, or if the specified collection is null

How do I make sure that this **"Collection  does not permit null elements"**

```
public class CollectionImpl {

public void checkList(){

    List<String> var1 = new ArrayList<String>();
     var1.add("One");
     var1.add("Two");
     var1.add("Three");

     System.out.println("var1 : " + var1);

     try{
         if(Collections.addAll(var1,"Four" , "Five" , null , "1")){
            System.out.println("True"); 
         }
     }
     catch(NullPointerException e){
         System.out.println("Caught Null Pointer Exception" + e);
     }
     catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
         System.out.println("Caught IllegalArgument Exception" + e);
     }
     finally{
         System.out.println("var1 : " + var1);
     }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
var1 : [1, 2, null]
True
var1 : [1, 2, null, 4, 5, null, 6]
```

Comment: I think the only way to make sure if a `Collection` implementation supports `null` element is to try to insert one and catch the `NullPointerException` if it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether a collection supports `null` elements is a property of the collection implementation itself. It's not a setting that can be changed on a particular instance of a collection. As others have mentioned, whether a collection permits `null` should always be documented in the class's specification.

Your example uses `ArrayList`, which permits `null` elements, so calling `addAll()` with `null` values will always successfully add them to the list.

An example of a `Collection` that doesn't permit `null` values is `ArrayDeque`. If you change your declaration of `var1` as follows:

```
Collection<String> var1 = new ArrayDeque<String>();
```

then you'll get a `NullPointerException` thrown from the call to `addAll()`.

Comment: Thanks! thats what I was looking for. Will check it out.

Answer (score 7):

> When does Java Collections throw a NullPointerException while using Collections.addAll()

The [`Collections.addAll` documentation tells us](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-T...-):

> `NullPointerException` - if `elements` contains one or more `null` values and `c` does not permit `null` elements, or if `c` or `elements` are `null`

Answering your second question:

> How do I make sure that this "Collection does not permit null elements"

By referring to the documentation for the class you're using. In [this case (`ArrayList`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), it's the second sentence:

> Implements all optional list operations, and **permits all elements, including `null`**.

*(My emphasis.)*

If you don't know what class you're dealing with (you just receive a `List` from other code and don't/can't know what kind of list it may be), you need to document in the method accepting it whether it needs to support `null` (since `List` doesn't have something that tells you; other than trying to add one and catching the exception if it doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

You presented the `Collection.addAll()` docs yourself.  They answer the question.

> How do I make sure that this "Collection does not permit null elements"[?]

If you're asking how to determine during development whether instances of a given collection class permit null elements, the answer is to read their documentation.  Most of the main `Collection` implementations (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `HashSet`, ...) do accept `null` values, though.  Perhaps the one you are most likely to encounter that does not support `null`s is a `TreeSet` that relies on elements' natural ordering or on a `Comparator` that rejects `null`s.

If you are asking how to determine at run time whether a collection accepts `null`s, then the only sure way is to try adding one.  If you get a `NullPointerException` then they are not supported.  Normally, it is better to *document* that externally-provided collections must accept `null`s if you rely on them to do so, or to document that such collections must not contain `null`s if indeed `null` elements are not meaningful.  Allowing your code to throw `NullPointerException` if such documented constraints are violated (and documenting, too, that it will do so) is perfectly reasonable.  Indeed, that's exactly what the `Collection`s classes do.